# How to set up an efficient watch on publications in planetary science?

Tags: publications, productivity

The number of journal on the topics tends to be quite high and most researchers of the field have yet to take on the habit of sharing their preprints on archive repositories (ArXiv or others).

Do you have any recommendation as to the best way to set up an efficient watch on what comes out ?

Comment: Go to your institution's library. Talk to a research librarian. Do what they say.

Answer (score 2):

There are different ways of keeping up to date that come to my mind:

- Using your favourite article indexing database listing articles in your field (e.g. [Scopus for life/biological sciences](https://www.scopus.com) or [Web of Science](https://images.webofknowledge.com/images/help/WOS/hp_my_citation_alerts.html)). Most databases allow you to set up 'Search Alerts', when results of a certain search string change. This can be done either via E-mail or RSS feed. Usually you can customize how often you get notified about such changes (daily/weekly summaries)
- Some citation management programs automatically notify you of recommended and related articles depending on your own collection of articles. For me, this often not only includes the newest research but also older classics and other highly related articles that might not necessarily be very recent.
- Thirdly, you can follow your peers on twitter and be notified of their most recent works that way. With the advantage of being able to start off discussions.

Answer (score 1):

- [Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.com)'s Follow feature, which sends you an email when you (or a given researcher) publish, receive a citation, or work related to yours (or the given researcher) is published;
- [Google Scholar Alerts](https://scholar.google.com/scholar_alerts?view_op=list_alerts), which sends you an email when Google Scholar discovers new results for a given search term;
- [Google Alerts](https://www.google.com/alerts), which sends you an email when Google Search
  discovers new results for a given search term.